# Azure Devops Pipelines for ionic iOS - Error of provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new on Azure Devops pipelines and working on pipelines for the ionic project to build the android and iOS builds.

For android, I have been succeeded and apk I also working fine as per expectations. But for iOS I am stuck from past 4 days and unable to proceed. Below is the my yaml file for pipeline.
Although, I have installed provision profile certificate, still facing error like below :
**error: "APP" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'APP' from project 'APP')**

Please suggest how to resolve this issue to generate the iOS build/ipa.

Note : Right now I am using same yaml file for both android and iOS, kindly suggest if the same is standard approach or not.

YAML File for pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  projectName: 'APP'

   #ios variables
  certSecureFileName: 'Certificates.p12'
  P12Password: 'PQRXYZ'
  signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
  ##  provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
  provisioningProfile: 'APP_Distribution.mobileprovision'
  sdkOption: 'iphoneos'
  configurationOption: 'Debug'
  workspaceName: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios/APP.xcworkspace'
  schemeName: 'APP'
  ArchivePath: ~/output/APP.xcarchive
  ExportIpaPath: ~/output/APP.ipa 

steps:    
        - script: sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli
          displayName: 'Install Ionic CLI'

        - task: Npm@1
          inputs:
            workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            command: install
          displayName: 'NPM Install'
                
        - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
          displayName: 'Install P12 Certificates'
          inputs:
            certSecureFile: '$(certSecureFileName)'
            certPwd: '$(P12Password)'
            signingIdentity: '$(signingIdentity)'
            deleteCert: true  

        - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
          displayName: 'Install App provisioning profile'
          inputs:
            provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
            provProfileSecureFile: '$(provisioningProfile)'
            removeProfile: true
        
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              sudo npm i -g cordova
              ionic build                          
              cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
              ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --buildConfig=build.json
              cd platforms/ios/
              xcodebuild clean archive -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP -archivePath build/APP.xcarchive
              xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/APP.xcarchive -exportPath build/export -exportOptionsPlist $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/exportOptions.plist
          displayName: "starting iOS build"  
          
- task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
          ## SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            contents: '**/*.ipa'
            TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
            overWrite: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)' 
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
```

**Error Log 22 Feb 2021:**

```
export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
2021-02-22T07:00:45.1045780Z     builtin-validationUtility /Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/build/emulator/APP.app
2021-02-22T07:00:45.1046100Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:45.1192290Z ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
2021-02-22T07:00:45.1193110Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0475340Z Command line invocation:
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0480470Z     /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild clean archive -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP -archivePath build/APP.xcarchive
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0481320Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0482090Z User defaults from command line:
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0482950Z     IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/build/APP.xcarchive
2021-02-22T07:00:46.0483570Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:46.9814740Z note: Using new build system
2021-02-22T07:00:46.9815300Z note: Building targets in parallel
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0653590Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0656080Z ** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0656650Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0780320Z note: Using new build system
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0781010Z note: Building targets in parallel
2021-02-22T07:00:47.0794200Z note: Planning build
2021-02-22T07:00:48.9307720Z note: Constructing build description
2021-02-22T07:00:49.1276620Z error: "APP" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'APP' from project 'APP')
2021-02-22T07:00:49.1290480Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:49.1293730Z ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
2021-02-22T07:00:49.1316830Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:49.9439170Z error: archive not found at path '/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/build/APP.xcarchive'
2021-02-22T07:00:49.9439810Z ** EXPORT FAILED **
2021-02-22T07:00:49.9439970Z 
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0313310Z ##[debug]$LASTEXITCODE: 65
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0521660Z ##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/local/bin/pwsh'
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0528430Z ##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/local/bin/pwsh'
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0543440Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0576690Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0589460Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0591720Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2021-02-22T07:00:50.0594820Z ##[section]Finishing: starting iOS build
```

**Xcode task 23 Feb 2021**

```
- task: Xcode@5
          displayName: 'Xcode archive'
          inputs:
            actions: archive
            xcWorkspacePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios/APP.xcworkspace'
            archivePath: 'APP.xcarchive'
            scheme: APP
            packageApp: true
            destinationTypeOption: devices
            exportOptions: plist
            exportOptionsPlist: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/exportOptions.plist'    
            exportPath: '$(agent.buildDirectory)/platforms/ios/output/iphoneos/Release'
            signingOption: manual
            signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
            provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

***Error Received is :***

```
2021-02-23T05:26:30.8370720Z ##[error]Error: The Xcode workspace was specified, but it does not exist or is not a directory: /Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/APP.xcworkspace
```

Answer (score 0):

When building with `Ionic`, use the `--buildConfig` flag to use a build configuration.
You can configure each platform, for each build type (`debug` or `release`).
You can specify a provisioning profile to use for `ios`, or a keystore for `android`.

As your issue concerns `ios`, I will not show the `android` config.

---

Create a `build.json` file at the root of your project with the following content :

```json
{
  "ios": {
    "release": {
      "provisioningProfile": "Your provisioning profile filename without .mobileprovision",
      "codeSignIdentity": "Your code sign identity name",
      "developmentTeam": "Your development team ID",
      "packageType": "app-store",
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0",
        "-destination generic/platform=iOS",
        "-sdk iphoneos"
      ]
    },
    "debug": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

*The provisioning profile should be at the root of your project, next to the build.json.*
*The `buildFlags` are optionnals.*

I have not tried using a path for `provisioningProfile`, nor including the `.mobileprovision` extension, but it might work as well.

---

Then build with the following command :

```sh
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --buildConfig=build.json
```

*If the `--release` flag is not used, it will default to `--debug`.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using above steps we are able to build successfully. But while Archive it gives the same issue.
Below are the updated tasks in YAML file. 
`
- task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              sudo npm i -g cordova
              ionic build                          
              ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --buildConfig=build.json
          displayName: "starting iOS build"  
`

Comment: ` 
- task: CocoaPods@0
          inputs:
            forceRepoUpdate: true
            workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios'
        
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:    
            script: |
              echo "Archive the iOS app"
              cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
              
              /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace $(workspaceName) -scheme "$(schemeName)" -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/APP.xcarchive
          displayName: 'Xcode Archive'
`

Comment: For Archive, it gives the same error: "APP" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'APP' from project 'APP').Request you to suggest here, so I can generate the ipa and copy the same to artifact.

Comment: Have tried 'cd '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios/APP.xcworkspace/APP
              xcodebuild -target APP-sdk APP -configuration Release' task to archive but getting error like 'Archive the iOS app
/Users/runner/work/_temp/ee64a008-17cd-4153-9b7d-0dea71d497df.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/Users/runner/work/_temp/ee64a008-17cd-4153-9b7d-0dea71d497df.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
' Any idea of this issue?

Comment: I can't really see the final file through all your comments. Can you update your original post with your updated yaml file ? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the yaml file. Post your suggestion, I am trying archive build to generate the .ipa file from .app but facing error like **unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' **. For this I am following article [link](http://www.splinter.com.au/xcode-4-command-line-builds-of-iphone-apps/).  Please suggest how can generate the ipa and copy the same to artifact.

Comment: Can you try these commands in a single task at first ? https://gist.github.com/Reqven/854b27489e95d10f25b0653903b4ff4d

Comment: Tried with the given suggestions by you. I have updated the yaml file in original post for your reference as well as log "Error Log 22 Feb 2021" from the error received for the "ARCHIVE FAILED". Could you please let me now what wrong is here. Thank you.

Comment: Any help? is there any issue related to code or certificates .. but build is been successful.. i dont know what is the issue with archive.. :-(

Comment: Maybe the `ionic build` succeed because it uses the local provisioning profile in the project, but the `xcodebuild` expects to find it in the default xcode directory, which is likely to be empty. What you can try is using the UUID instead of the name of the provisioning profile in the `exportOptions.plist` file. If it still doesn't work, you should definitely try the dedicated [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) for archiving your app.

Comment: Tried with the xcode task also, but it gives the error like "##[error]Error: The Xcode workspace was specified, but it does not exist or is not a directory: /Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/APP.xcworkspace... :-( .. I have updated the original post also with the Xcode task, please let me know in case you can help me out to resolve the issue.. Thanks you. 
"

Comment: I am confused about the workspace .. is it the wrong path I am referring?

Comment: Multiple things could cause that error. Is there a way I could look at your project architecture and your Azure setup by myself to try things out ?